# Change Language in Runtime

Tags: php, codeigniter, multilingual

I'm trying to change the language of one webapp in realtime using codeigniter.

I follow the online documentation, create the folder for language2 with all the traductions, but when I do:

```
$this->config->set_item('language', 'portuguese');
```

It don't change the lang, the only way it works is changing the config file ex:

```
$config['language'] = "english";
```

But what I need is change in realtime not changing the config of the framework.

Regards,
Pedro

Comment: When are you calling `$this->config->set_item('language', 'portuguese');` ?  In the controller constructor or later?

Comment: Yes, but *where* in the controller?  In the constructor or in the method?

Comment: In the method not in the constructor

Comment: Try in the constructor.  I suspect that by the time the method is called, the language file has already been loaded.

Comment: I try that but still no change! Thanks anyway ;)

Answer (score 2):

you can use this code. (this example for ion_auth)

```
$this->config->set_item('language', 'portuguese');  
$this->lang->is_loaded = array();
$this->lang->load('ion_auth', 'portuguese');
```

this code used in constractor .

> $this->lang->is_loaded = array();
>   top line empty laded languages.

Answer (score 1):

Use hooks instead of class constructor, or even extend the Controller to MY_Controller and call in it's constructor.